# Doctrine relations with intermediate table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a `Product` and `Category` entity that works and looks like this: [doctrine2: in a one-to-many bidirectional relationship, how to save from the inverse side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618514/doctrine2-in-a-one-to-many-bidirectional-relationship-how-to-save-from-the-inv)

However in reality I have three tables:

product:

```
id | ...
```

category:

```
id | ...
```

productcategory:

```
product_id | category_id
```

How do I change my two entities to use an intermediate table? Or should I create a third entity?