# Symfony Not able to save manyToOne bidirectional Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called `survey` and I have an entity called `Creditcards`

`Creditcard` is linked with `survey` using `manyToOne`

`survey` is linked with `Creditcard` using `oneToMany`

The survey has bunch of financial related questions which gets saved in `survey` table and it also asks user for their creditcard related details which then gets saved in `Creditcard` table, since user can have more than 1 card so they can add multiple card details and this is where the `manyToOne` and `oneToMany` comes into play.

**This is my `Creditcard.orm.yml`**

```
ExampleBundle\Entity\Creditcards:
    type: entity
    table: creditcards
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        surveyId:
            type: integer
            column: survey_id
        balance:
            type: integer
        amountDue:
            type: integer
            column: amount_due
        interestRate:
            type: integer
            column: interest_rate
    manyToOne:
        survey:
            targetEntity: ExampleBundle\Entity\survey
            inversedBy: creditcards
            joinColumn:
                name: survey_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: CASCADE
    lifecycleCallbacks: {   }
```

**This is my `Creditcard` Entity**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Creditcards
 */
class Creditcards
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $surveyId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $balance;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $amountDue;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $interestRate;

    /**
     * @var \ExampleBundle\Entity\Survey
     */
    private $survey;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set surveyId
     *
     * @param integer $surveyId
     * @return integer
     */
    public function setSurveyId($surveyId)
    {
        $this->surveyId = $surveyId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get survey
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getSurveyId()
    {
        return $this->surveyId;
    }

    /**
     * Set balance
     *
     * @param integer $balance
     * @return Creditcards
     */
    public function setBalance($balance)
    {
        $this->balance = $balance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get balance
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }

    /**
     * Set amountDue
     *
     * @param integer $amountDue
     * @return Creditcards
     */
    public function setAmountDue($amountDue)
    {
        $this->amountDue = $amountDue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amountDue
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAmountDue()
    {
        return $this->amountDue;
    }

    /**
     * Set interestRate
     *
     * @param integer $interestRate
     * @return Creditcards
     */
    public function setInterestRate($interestRate)
    {
        $this->interestRate = $interestRate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get interestRate
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getInterestRate()
    {
        return $this->interestRate;
    }



    /**
     * Set survey
     *
     * @param \ExampleBundle\Entity\survey $survey
     * @return Creditcards
     */
    public function setSurvey(\ExampleBundle\Entity\survey $survey = null)
    {
        $this->survey = $survey;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get survey
     *
     * @return \ExampleBundle\Entity\survey
     */
    public function getSurvey()
    {
        return $this->survey;
    }
    public function addSurvey(\ExampleBundle\Entity\survey $survey)
    {
        $survey->addCreditcard($this);

        $this->survey->add($survey);
    }
}
```

**This is my `survey.orm.yml`**

Its pretty long so I will remove some part of it to keep it related to the question

```
ExampleBundle\Entity\survey:
    type: entity
    table: survey
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        homeLoanMonthlyRepayments:
            type: integer
            column: home_loan_monthly_repayments
            nullable: true
        homeLoanTotalOutstanding:
            type: integer
            column: home_loan_total_outstanding
            nullable: true
        carLoanMonthlyRepayments:
            type: integer
            column: car_loan_monthly_repayments
            nullable: true
        carLoanTotalOutstanding:
            type: integer
            column: car_loan_total_outstanding
            nullable: true
        personalLoanMonthlyRepayments:
            type: integer
            column: personal_loan_monthly_repayments
            nullable: true
        personalLoanTotalOutstanding:
            type: integer
            column: personal_loan_total_outstanding
            nullable: true
        otherLoanMonthlyRepayments:
            type: integer
            column: other_loan_monthly_repayments
            nullable: true
        otherLoanTotalOutstanding:
            type: integer
            column: other_loan_total_outstanding
            nullable: true

        userID:
            type: integer
            column: user_id
            nullable: true

    oneToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: UserBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: survey
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id

    oneToMany:
        creditcards:
            targetEntity: ExampleBundle\Entity\Creditcards
            mappedBy: survey
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**This is my `survey` Entity**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * survey
 */
class survey
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;     

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set homeLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @param integer $homeLoanMonthlyRepayments
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setHomeLoanMonthlyRepayments($homeLoanMonthlyRepayments)
    {
        $this->homeLoanMonthlyRepayments = $homeLoanMonthlyRepayments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get homeLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHomeLoanMonthlyRepayments()
    {
        return $this->homeLoanMonthlyRepayments;
    }

    /**
     * Set homeLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @param integer $homeLoanTotalOutstanding
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setHomeLoanTotalOutstanding($homeLoanTotalOutstanding)
    {
        $this->homeLoanTotalOutstanding = $homeLoanTotalOutstanding;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get homeLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHomeLoanTotalOutstanding()
    {
        return $this->homeLoanTotalOutstanding;
    }

    /**
     * Set carLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @param integer $carLoanMonthlyRepayments
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setCarLoanMonthlyRepayments($carLoanMonthlyRepayments)
    {
        $this->carLoanMonthlyRepayments = $carLoanMonthlyRepayments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get carLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCarLoanMonthlyRepayments()
    {
        return $this->carLoanMonthlyRepayments;
    }

    /**
     * Set carLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @param integer $carLoanTotalOutstanding
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setCarLoanTotalOutstanding($carLoanTotalOutstanding)
    {
        $this->carLoanTotalOutstanding = $carLoanTotalOutstanding;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get carLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCarLoanTotalOutstanding()
    {
        return $this->carLoanTotalOutstanding;
    }

    /**
     * Set personalLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @param integer $personalLoanMonthlyRepayments
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setPersonalLoanMonthlyRepayments($personalLoanMonthlyRepayments)
    {
        $this->personalLoanMonthlyRepayments = $personalLoanMonthlyRepayments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personalLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPersonalLoanMonthlyRepayments()
    {
        return $this->personalLoanMonthlyRepayments;
    }

    /**
     * Set personalLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @param integer $personalLoanTotalOutstanding
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setPersonalLoanTotalOutstanding($personalLoanTotalOutstanding)
    {
        $this->personalLoanTotalOutstanding = $personalLoanTotalOutstanding;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personalLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPersonalLoanTotalOutstanding()
    {
        return $this->personalLoanTotalOutstanding;
    }

    /**
     * Set otherLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @param integer $otherLoanMonthlyRepayments
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setOtherLoanMonthlyRepayments($otherLoanMonthlyRepayments)
    {
        $this->otherLoanMonthlyRepayments = $otherLoanMonthlyRepayments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get otherLoanMonthlyRepayments
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getOtherLoanMonthlyRepayments()
    {
        return $this->otherLoanMonthlyRepayments;
    }

    /**
     * Set otherLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @param integer $otherLoanTotalOutstanding
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setOtherLoanTotalOutstanding($otherLoanTotalOutstanding)
    {
        $this->otherLoanTotalOutstanding = $otherLoanTotalOutstanding;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get otherLoanTotalOutstanding
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getOtherLoanTotalOutstanding()
    {
        return $this->otherLoanTotalOutstanding;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $userID;


    /**
     * Set userID
     *
     * @param integer $userID
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setUserID($userID)
    {
        $this->userID = $userID;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserID()
    {
        return $this->userID;
    }
    /**
     * @var \UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \ExampletBundle\Entity\Creditcards
     */
    private $creditcards;


    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return survey
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getUser();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->creditcards = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add creditcards
     *
     * @param \ExampletBundle\Entity\Creditcards $creditcards
     * @return survey
     */
    public function addCreditcard(\ExampleBundle\Entity\Creditcards $creditcards)
    {
        if (!$this->creditcards->contains($creditcards)) {
            $this->creditcards->add($creditcards);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove creditcards
     *
     * @param \ExampletBundle\Entity\Creditcards $creditcards
     */
    public function removeCreditcard(\ExampleBundle\Entity\Creditcards $creditcards)
    {
        $this->creditcards->removeElement($creditcards);
    }

    /**
     * Get creditcards
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCreditcards()
    {
        return $this->creditcards;
    }
}
```

**The Form that gets called in controller and passed to the twig**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class debtType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('homeLoanMonthlyRepayments')
            ->add('homeLoanTotalOutstanding')
            ->add('carLoanMonthlyRepayments')
            ->add('carLoanTotalOutstanding')
            ->add('personalLoanMonthlyRepayments')
            ->add('personalLoanTotalOutstanding')
            ->add('otherLoanMonthlyRepayments')
            ->add('otherLoanTotalOutstanding')            
            ->add('creditcards', 'collection', array('type' => new CreditcardsType(), 'allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false,
            ));

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ExampleBundle\Entity\survey'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'examplebundle_debt';
    }
}
```

Finally my `debtAction` that processes the form and tries to save the data

```
public function debtAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //get user id of currently logged in user
    $userId = $this->getUser()->getId();

    //get survey object of currently logged in user
    $userExpensesInfo = $em->getRepository('ExampleBundle:survey')->findOneByuserID($userId);
   $form = $this->createForm(new debtType(), $userExpensesInfo);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        if($form->isValid()){
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseFood($form->get('homeLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseFood($form->get('homeLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseHousing($form->get('carLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseTransport($form->get('carLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseFun($form->get('personalLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseClothing($form->get('personalLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpenseUtil($form->get('otherLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->setExpensePersonal($form->get('otherLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
            $userExpensesInfo->getCreditcards()->add($form->get('creditcards')->getData());                
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice',
                'Your loan information has been saved'
            );
            return $this->render('ExampleBundle:Default/dashboard:debt.html.twig', array(
                'form'=>$form->createView(),
            ));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('ExampleBundle:Default/dashboard:debt.html.twig', array(
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I have gone through step by step through [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) article but I just cant get the save to work, when I try to save it this is the error I get

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'ExampleBundle\Entity\survey#creditcards' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: ExampleBundle\Entity\Creditcards@000000001bbd76da000000008bbf1e28. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'ExampleBundle\Entity\Creditcards#__toString()' to get a clue.
500 Internal Server Error - ORMInvalidArgumentException
```

The article I refereed above does talk about it at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) section, I followed the instruction and no matter what I do I just cant get passed this error. Its over 6 hours now that I am trying to solve this and I just cant think straight any more.

I will really appreciate if I can get some here on this.

**UPDATE:**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ExampleBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: are you sure that you 'added' to both sides of your relation? only adding it to one will not result in correctly persisting the object.

Comment: @LBA are you referring to if I added `cascade: ["persist"]` to both sides of the relationship?

Comment: no, see the accepted answer here e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618514/doctrine2-in-a-one-to-many-bidirectional-relationship-how-to-save-from-the-inv?rq=1

Comment: I had a look at the link you sent me, couple of things I dont understand where is the function `setProductCategory` being called? and inside this function it is setting a property `productCategory` which i do not see being defined in the Entity?

Comment: what the article says is: if you do $myEntity->addToCollection($newElement) then you must as well do: $newElement->setEntity($myEntity) before you persist and flush - otherwise in this case your myEntity will never have newElement persisted.

Comment: I am pretty sure you're creditcard is not getting persisted and you need to manually persist it as well as setting the survey to it.

Comment: I have followed the example you gave me but I still see the same error, what I am doing now in the controller is trying to use the loop just to check if I this way data gets saved or not foreach($form->get('creditcards')->getData() as $cc) { $userExpensesInfo->addCreditcard($cc);                   $creditcards->setSurveyId(1); }'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90229/discussion-between-baig-and-lba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. It seems that I was not saving the credit card details by using Symfony properly.

Inside my controller I was setting up the data manually which was totally not required in my case

```
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseFood($form->get('homeLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseFood($form->get('homeLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseHousing($form->get('carLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseTransport($form->get('carLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseFun($form->get('personalLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseClothing($form->get('personalLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpenseUtil($form->get('otherLoanMonthlyRepayments')->getData());
$userExpensesInfo->setExpensePersonal($form->get('otherLoanTotalOutstanding')->getData()); $userExpensesInfo->getCreditcards()->add($form->get('creditcards')->getData());
```

Then I had to change my function `addCreditCard` to as following

```
public function addCreditCard(CreditCard $card)
{
    if (!$this->creditcards->contains($card)) {
        $this->creditcards->add($card);
    }
    $card->setSurvey($this);
}
```

After than it was working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `cascade: ["persist"]` to your oneToMany mapping in the survey yaml.

And by the way: Class names should be singular and capitalized.

Comment: Yes I tried that too but that gives me another error `The class 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces ExampleBundle\Entity, UserBundle\Entity`

Comment: There might be a problem with your doctrine config, can you post it?

Comment: If you are referring to `config.yml` then I have updated my question and added that under update heading

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve (after checking back) is a bidirectional many-to-many association as seen in chapter 5.9 in the documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

make you sure to define your "owning" side correctly and depending on it set and persist both sides of the association (see 5.9.1 in above's link) - otherwise your entity cannot be correctly persisted.

If you just need a unidirectional many-to-many check 5.8 in the provided documentation.

Comment: okay so i spent many hours since we chatted on this issue and unfortunately the relationship applies to it is not many-to-many, I finally got it to work. My relationship is setup right my only problem was the way I was saving the data in controller once i fixed that it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: glad you found it - really wanted to help but didn't see that.